# XNamespace url is written in XAttribute when I create my XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm creating a XML with namespaces but url are written in XAttribute elements instead of Namespace "prefix"
This is what I get as output

```
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701"
         xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701">   
   <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5" />  
       <uml:Model xmi:type="{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701}Model" name="EA_Model">
          <packagedElement xmi:type="{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701}Package" xmi:id="1212" name="Logical View">
          <packagedElement xmi:type="{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701}Class" xmi:id="35798" name="MyClass">
```

but I should generate something like this..

```
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701"
         xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701">   
   <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5" />  
       <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model">
          <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="1212" name="Logical View">
          <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="35798" name="MyClass">
```

My Code:

```
XNamespace uml = "http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701";
XNamespace xmi = "http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701";

XElement rootElement = new XElement(xmi + "XMI", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "uml", "http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701"), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xmi", "http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701"));
doc.Add(rootElement);

rootElement.Add(new XElement(xmi+"Documentation", new XAttribute("exporter", "Enterprise Architect"), new XAttribute("exporterVersion", "6.5")));

XElement modelNode = new XElement(uml + "Model", new XAttribute(xmi + "type", uml + "Model"), new XAttribute("name", "EA_Model"));
rootElement.Add(modelNode);

XElement logicalViewElement = new XElement("packagedElement", new XAttribute(xmi + "type", uml + "Package"), new XAttribute(xmi + "id", project.Id), new XAttribute("name", "Logical View"));
modelNode.Add(logicalViewElement);

Dictionary<string, XElement> entityNodes = new Dictionary<string, XElement>();
foreach (BusinessEntityDataObject entity in project.BusinessEntities)
{
    XElement entityElement = 
        new XElement("packagedElement", 
           new XAttribute(xmi+"type",uml+"Class"),
           new XAttribute(xmi+"id",entity.Id), 
           new XAttribute("name",entity.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating XNamespace with string value

```
 new XAttribute(xmi + "type", uml + "Class")
```

You should build attribute value manually:

```
 new XAttribute(xmi + "type", "uml:Class")
```

`XAttribute` constructor has two parameters - first one expects `XName` and second one expects simple `object`. When you combine `XNamespace` with `string` you get `string` result, which looks like `xmi.ToString() + attributeName`, which equals `"{http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701}type"`. Thus `XNode` type has defined implicit conversion from string, this string can be converted to `XName` instance.

In second case `uml + "Class"` also combined into string `"{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701}Class"`. But second argument of constructor should be of type `object`, and this string satisfies that requirement, so nothing is converted to `XName` and you have your combined string as attribute value.